# Directsound logarithm volume to linear volume slider

Tags: c#, directx, directsound

I am developing an music player with DirectX.DirectSound. I have a problem with the volume. The directsound volume is logarithm. This means that with silent sounds, is much more sensitive to small variations in amplitude than with loud sounds. It also means that with a linear volume slider we have a logarithmic sensation of volume variations, and that just doesn't feel right. My question is: How can I make it linear?
My code until here is:

```
 if (trkBalance.Value == trkBalance.Minimum)
            {
                foreGroundSound.Volume = (int)DS.Volume.Min;

            }
            else if (trkBalance.Value == trkBalance.Maximum)
            {
                foreGroundSound.Volume = (int)DS.Volume.Max;
            }
            else
            {
               foreGroundSound.Volume = (int)(-5000 * Math.Log10(100 - trkBalance.Value));
            }
```

Comment: In what range is `trkBalance.Value`? If you want to revert the logarithmic scale, you have to use the inverse function (`Math.Exp`). What values are `DS.Volume.Min/Max`? You need to find a function `v(t) = c * Math.Exp(t)` where `v(minValue) == DS.Volume.Min` and `v(maxValue) == DS.Volume.Max`.

Comment: @NicoSchertler It is for -10000 Min and 0  for Maximum and my trackbar is 0-100. I am trying with `foreGroundSound.Volume = Math.Exp((trkBalance.Value * 100) - 10000)` but with no luck.

Answer (score 3):

There is a rule of thumb to determine the perceived loudness:

> A difference of 10 dB (doubleValue) results in a sound twice / half as loud as the original source.

With that in mind we can create a formula that maps the attenuation to the sound pressure level.

But at first we have to calculate the actual attenuation (as a fraction). DirectSound can attenuate a sound by 100 dB, which is an attenuation of `1/2^(100/doubleValue)`. This is the value for the minimum trackbar value. The maximum value is 1 (no change). So overall:

```
doubleValue = 10;
minimumAttenuation = 1/2^(100/doubleValue)
attenuation = minimumAttenuation + trkBalance.Value / 100 * (1 - minimumAttenuation);
```

Now we have a value within valid range. Now we need to find the sound pressure level for this attenuation.

And we know that the loudness doubles every 10 db (doubleValue):

```
attenuation = 2^(db/doubleValue) //ln
ln(attenuation) = db / doubleValue * ln(2)
db = doubleValue * ln(attenuation) / ln(2)
```

And since DirectSound takes hundreths dB, you can use

```
foreGroundSound.Volume = db * 100;
```

---

Those are just some theoretical thoughts based on wikipedia information. It might or might not work. Just try it.

Comment: `int  attenuation = 1 / 1024 + trkBalance.Value / 100 * 1023 / 1024;
 double db = 10 * Math.Log10(attenuation) / Math.Log10(2);
 label8.Text = (db * 100).ToString();`
You mean something like this? Unfortunately this formula gives -infinite.

Comment: You should consider language specific type safety. I.e. use 1f etc. to avoid truncating to int.

Comment: No, my question is if ln = log with base 2. Thanxs

Comment: ln is the logarithmus naturalis (base e). Though, you can use any other logarithmus you like (e.g. the `Log10`). The reason why the formula gives -infinite is the truncation to integer. `attenuation` should be a float or double variable and therefore: `double attenuation = 1.0 / 1024.0 + t / 100.0 * 1023.0 / 1024.0; `

Comment: `double attenuation = 1.0 / 1024.0 + trkBalance.Value / 100.0 * 1023.0 / 1024.0;
                    double db = 3 * Math.Log10(attenuation) / Math.Log10(2);
                    foreGroundSound.Volume = (int)(db * 100);`

This is the solution and I am happy ! Thank you

Comment: @ Nico Schertler  Ok and an other question how can I extend the db range to -10.000? Because this formula is going only until -3000. Thank you

Comment: Because you changed my `10` to `3` (`db = 10 * Math.Log10...`).

Comment: I did it because 3db is the difference in a sound half as loud as the original source for SPL. Is this number shows that difference ? Thank you

Comment: Ok, you have to change the attenuation then. I edited the answer to reflect that. You can now choose a custom `doubleValue` (3 in your case).

Comment: can you show me the actual code to convert a double value with a range from 0 to 1 to a directsound value and back? @NicoSchertler

Comment: @thefiloe: It's all there. Calculate the attenuation (based on a `doubleValue` of 10) and then calculate `db`. `100 * db` is then your DirectSound volume. Is there something you're having trouble with?

Comment: what exactly is "doubleValue"?

Comment: @thefiloe The difference of sound pressure levels where the perceived loudness doubles. You can assume `10`.